# Memory Leak using opencvsharp

Tags: c#, opencv

So I'm trying to use [opencvsharp](http://code.google.com/p/opencvsharp/) to create an augmented reality tracker, and I'm having a problem with a memory leak.

I am trying to identify rectangles from a camera image (which are my markers) I'm fairly sure that the offending code is

```
        CvSeq<CvPoint> firstcontour = null;

        List<MarkerRectangle> rectangles = new List<MarkerRectangle>();

        CvMemStorage storage = Cv.CreateMemStorage(0);
        CvMemStorage storagepoly = Cv.CreateMemStorage(0);

        IplImage gsImageContour = Cv.CreateImage(Cv.GetSize(thresholdedImage), thresholdedImage.Depth, thresholdedImage.NChannels);
        //find contours
        Cv.Copy(thresholdedImage, gsImageContour, null);
        int contourCount = Cv.FindContours(gsImageContour, storage, out firstcontour, CvContour.SizeOf,
             ContourRetrieval.CComp, ContourChain.ApproxSimple, Cv.Point(0, 0));

        CvSeq<CvPoint>  polycontour = firstcontour.ApproxPoly(CvContour.SizeOf, storagepoly, ApproxPolyMethod.DP, 4, true);
```

I'm fairly sure the offending lines are:

```
        int contourCount = Cv.FindContours(gsImageContour, storage, out firstcontour, CvContour.SizeOf, ContourRetrieval.CComp, ContourChain.ApproxSimple, Cv.Point(0, 0));
```

and/or

```
        CvSeq<CvPoint>  polycontour = firstcontour.ApproxPoly(CvContour.SizeOf, storagepoly, ApproxPolyMethod.DP, 4, true);
```

However I'm not sure what I might be doing wrong, as they are not stored in any global variables i would expect the memory to be freed when they get to the end of the method.

It may be [this](http://code.google.com/p/opencvsharp/issues/detail?id=45) bug, in which case I suspect I lack the technical expertise to fix it, as, with the exception of a couple of courses at uni, i haven't worked with unmanaged code. However i tried implementing the fix it lists under additional information and that didn't work so instead i'm thinking maybe it is not the cause of my problem.

Comment: How are you determining that there's a memory leak here? Furthermore your expectation that the memory will be freed once the variables fall out of scope is invalid - assuming these are finalizable objects (as I would expect them to if they are holding unmanaged resources) then they will become eligible for finalization once they are no longer referenced, but finalization (and associated release of unmanaged memory) will not occur until the garbage collector runs (and even then may not occur immediately depending on the generation collected).